# Como sacar un LocalDate de un Jspinner que tiene un Date?

Tags: java

pues eso, tengo una fecha, que el usuario mete por un spinner,como puedo guardar eso en un LocalDate, que es como guardo la variable de fecha de nacimiento?
gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que te pases por la página [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date date=(Date) jSpinner1.getValue();

LocalDate fecha=Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).
atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();